# Use Python turtle to print postal bar code from user's zipcode input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I know that I probably have a lot wrong here, and I'm just a beginner, but I have absolutely no clue what's a easier way to correspond an entered digit to a postal bar code. My objective here, or what I'm trying to do, is input the user's zip code, and, with every digit entered, convert it into lines (short and long), printing out a bar code.

This is what I have so far.  I've already defined each number and its corresponding lines according to the post bar code conversion table:

```
import turtle

t = turtle
t.pensize(2)
t.hideturtle()
t.left(90)
t.speed('fastest')

def print_zero():
    long()
    long()
    short()
    short()
    short()
    return

def print_one():
     short()
     short()
     short()
     long()
     long()

...
```

Now I do this all the way to `print_nine()`.
After `print_nine()`, I enter...

```
def long():
    t.fd(14)
    t.up()
    t.bk(14)
    t.right(90)
    t.fd(6)
    t.down()

def short():
    t.fd(6)
    t.up()
    t.bk(6)
    t.right(90)
    t.fd(6)
    t.left(90)
    t.down()

t.up()
t.goto(0, -50)
t.down()

if digit == '0':
    print(print_zero)

elif digit == '1':
    print(print_one)

elif digit == '2':
    print(print_two)

elif digit == '3':
    print(print_three)

elif digit == '4':
    print(print_four)

elif digit == '5':
    print(print_five)

elif digit == '6':
    print(print_six)

elif digit == '7':
    print(print_seven)

elif digit == '8':
    print(print_eight)

elif digit == '9':
    print(print_nine)

else:
    print('Please print a valid zipcode.')
```

I also need to call `main()`, would I place main at the end of the code?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you want to use a function you have to call it with `()`. And looking at your code you might want to dive into topics like function arguments and dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the next step I would take in (re)arranging your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def short(t):
    t.forward(6)
    t.penup()
    t.backward(6)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(6)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()

def long(t):
    t.forward(14)
    t.penup()
    t.backward(14)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(6)
    t.left(90)
    t.down()

def print_zero(t):
    long(t)
    long(t)
    short(t)
    short(t)
    short(t)

def print_one(t):
    short(t)
    short(t)
    short(t)
    long(t)
    long(t)

# ...

DIGITS = {
    '0': print_zero,
    '1': print_one,
    # ...
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = Screen()
    screen.title('Zip Code to Bar Code')

    turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.pensize(2)
    turtle.left(90)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-50)
    turtle.pendown()

    zipcode = screen.textinput('Zip Code', 'Please enter a valid zipcode:')

    if zipcode:
        for digit in zipcode:
            if digit in DIGITS:
                DIGITS[digit](turtle)

    screen.mainloop()
```

Now it should be a series of small steps to define a `main()` function; define some constants at the top of your code so that numbers like 6, 14, -50 and 2 don't show up in the middle of it and can be easily adjusted; add error messages (e.g. what if `digit` isn't in `DIGITS`.)  Keep in mind that `main()` is how you want to use your code right now, but everything outside of `main()` should be designed for someone else to use as a library to solve their problem in the future.

[image]

Comment: 1. When you say "constants", would you mean something like "if, else" to print an error message so that, as you say, "numbers like 6, 14, -50 and 2 don't show up"? 2.  Also, in DIGITS[digit])turtle), does this line of code print out the bar code?  3. Lastly, what do you mean but what can I do to also design the code so that it can be "designed for someone else to use as a library"?

Comment: @Vee, 1) by constants I mean top level declarations like, `SHORT_LENGTH = 6` and then later on we write `t.fd(SHORT_LENGTH)` instead of `t.fd(6)`; 2) The `DIGITS[digit](turtle)` expression looks in the dictionary `DIGITS` for the function stored under the key `digit` and then calls that function with argument `turtle`; 3) If I were to `import` your Python file as a library to draw bar codes in my Python program, what would be generic enough for me to use for my (or any) application and what is specific to your application?  Make sure these are cleanly separated.

Comment: Makes sense, I have one last question. How how would I be able to automatically add two long lines at both ends of the post bar code? I tried doing 'long(t) + DIGITS[digit](turtle) + long(t)'  I'm assuming, I did that wrong as I just come up with an error? Can you please point me in the direction as to where I should be putting  'long(t)'  at?